# What is the phrase used here: He wore his arms off grabbing things first

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

I read an article and there are two sentences in it:

> "He wore his arms off grabbing things first. He wore his legs off pushing in every place first."

I look up "wear off " in the M-W dictionary, and it says:
"gradually decrease, disappear, or stop". But in my opinion, it doesn't make sense here.

What is the meaning of "wear off" here?

Comment: I would expect the quotes to be "wore his arms out" and "wore his legs out", not "wore his arms off" and "wore his legs off".  (I speak American English.)

Comment: What is the source of the quote?

Comment: My daughter's book "Vocabu-Lit" Book B, page 44.
http://i125.photobucket.com/albums/p58/timchk/IMG_8194.jpg
What does "wore his arm out" and "wore his legs out" mean?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the verbs is not direct. More like a metaphor, if you like.

It makes more sense if you imagine the persons as robots. And robots, while working veery hard for a very long time, especially if they are not maintained and greased properly, they start losing metal / material due to friction, erosion, heat...

So the meaning would be: my hands "eroded" (became shorter / thinner) because of the very much work done.

Bottom line: "became very tired"

Answer (score 0):

By saying "I wore my arms out," it implies that I "used/worked my arms *so* much that they have become extremely tired."

This kind of phrase is something you will not find in a standard dictionary. They are called "Phrasal Verbs." For more information on this term "wearing out," try this [link](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/wear-out).